# Merge two field into the first field where product_id is the same and attribute_id is 53 or 54

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to enter this question as specifically as possible

In MySQL I have a table oc_product_attribute

I have a table what looks like this

```
-------------------------------
|product_id|attribute_id|text |
-------------------------------
|2125      |53          |text1|
|2125      |54          |text2|
|2356      |53          |text3|
|2356      |54          |text4|
-------------------------------
```

I want to get rid of attribute_id 54 and append the text in this field to the text in attribute_id 53 with a comma as separator.

So basicly to look like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|product_id|attribute_id|text        |
--------------------------------------
|2125      |53          |text1, text2|
|2356      |53          |text3, text4|
--------------------------------------
```

I also have other attribute_is's which I don't want to change.

Anyone know how to?

Comment: You are suppose to show what you did so far...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: use a case statement to change the 54 to 53 `Case when attribute_ID = 54 then 53 else attribute_ID end as Attribute_ID` then use `group_concat()` to combine the text  along with a group by on product_ID and attribute_ID.  but you didn't specify if you want this as table change or as a query.  Also, if table change I think you're going the wrong way; as you now have multiple values in a single field which is a no-no in database design.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong... 53 and 54 are NOT just example values but they are exactly those you want, and you need to update those value, not just show them... isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY in combination with MIN, GROUP_CONCAT

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

SELECT 
    product_id
  , MIN(attribute_id) AS attribute_id 
  , GROUP_CONCAT(text) AS text
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE
 attribute_id IN(53, 54)
GROUP BY 
 product_id
ORDER BY 
 product_id ASC
```

Comment: This gives me a correct output. How do I update the text field. Is this possible?

Comment: @Gerjan Krul not advicable to update normalized data and make it unnormalized.. besides you need to have two queries a update and delete query.

Answer (score 0):

1. To combine 53 and 54 you need to use a case statement since you have other values you want to persist.
2. You can then use group_concat() to combine the values into one field

.

```
SELECT product_Id
     , CASE WHEN attribute_id = 54 THEN 53 ELSE attribute_id END as attribute_Id
     , group_concat(text SEPARATOR ',') as text
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY product_Id
       , CASE WHEN attribute_id = 54 THEN 53 ELSE attribute_id END
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I am not a developer. But nothing is happening.
Should'nt I use a update command? Look like I am only selecting.

Comment: a comment to your original post states: "you didn't specify if you want this as table change or as a query. Also, if table change I think you're going the wrong way; as you now have multiple values in a single field which is a no-no in database design."

Comment: I understand what you say about the multiple values but the thing is that something went wrong during the import process. The value in 54 should really be in the 53 attribute.
To be more exact, it is about clothing en attribute 53 describes the material and its weight per square meter. Accidentally the weight per square meter was imported in the 54 attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is all you need.

```
SELECT `product_id`, `attribute_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`text`) AS "text"
FROM `oc_product_attribute`
GROUP BY `product_id`
ORDER BY `product_id`, `attribute_id`
```

Sorting the `attribute_id` will make you take always the first value

**UPDATE**

It seems the question were much more specific then what I thougth, this is what I **think** you're asking for...
Of course, the suggestions you recived by comments in other answer are pretty good and you should think about them...

```
UPDATE `oc_product_attribute` as prod53
INNER JOIN `oc_product_attribute` as prod54
ON `prod53`.`product_id` = `prod54`.`product_id`
AND `prod53`.`attribute_id` = 53
AND `prod54`.`attribute_id` = 54
SET `prod53`.`text` = CONCAT(`prod53`.`text`, ", ", `prod54`.`text`);

DELETE `prod54`.*
FROM `oc_product_attribute` as prod53
INNER JOIN `oc_product_attribute` as prod54
ON `prod53`.`product_id` = `prod54`.`product_id`
AND `prod53`.`attribute_id` = 53
AND `prod54`.`attribute_id` = 54;
```

**WARNING** Test them before execution, using a transaction without committing it or trying `SELECT` instead of editing them... If the query shows what you expect, then procede.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group_concat()` like

```
select product_id,
attribute_id,
group_concat(text) as text
from oc_product_attribute
group by product_id;
```